# How to update the text indicator to show progress from the progress bar?

Tags: javascript, html

I have this HTML:

```
<head>
  <script language=JavaScript></script> 
</head>
<body>
  <progress value="0" max="100" id=p1></progress>
  <input type=button value='Increse' onClick='incr();'>
  <div id="numValue">0%</div>
</body>
</html>
```

with this source code:

```
<script language=JavaScript> 
  <!--
  function incr() { 
    var v1=document.getElementById('p1').value;
    document.getElementById("p1").value= v1 + 5;
    var val = document.getElementById("numValue");
  }
  //-->
</script>
```

I don't know how to update the `numValue` text indicator to show me the progress value as the progress bar completes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 function incr() { 
   var v1=document.getElementById('p1').value;
   document.getElementById("p1").value= v1 + 5;
   var val = document.getElementById("numValue");
   document.getElementById("numValue").innerHTML = (v1 + 5) + "%"

}
```

but it's better to write like this :

```
 function incr() { 
  var progress = document.getElementById('p1');
  var numValue = document.getElementById("numValue")
  var newValue = progress.value + 5;
  progress.value = newValue;
  numValue.innerHTML = newValue + "%"

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the following code after `var val = document.getElementById("numValue");`

`val.innerHTML = v1 + 5+'%'`

Answer (score 0):

why you do not use jquery?

with jquery you can do this :

```
$(document).ready (function (){
  function incr ()
  {
     $('#numValue').val ($('#p1').val ()+5+'%');
 }
     $('input [type="button"]').click (function (){incr ();});
});
```